# Calling a function in a function by jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, model-view-controller

I have two function, it has indexes. i have to call these two function in the third function and used it ..

```
function FutureDateValidation(Indx) {

var ExpDateTxt = '#txtExpDate' + Indx.toString();
var mCurDt = $('#CurDate').val();
var ExpDate = $(ExpDateTxt).val();
var serverDate = new Date('@ViewBag.ServerDate');
alert(serverDate);
if (CompareDates(mCurDt, ExpDate) == false) {

    PopupMessage("Required", " The Expiry date should be greater than current date", "alert");

    //        $('#' + ExpDateTxt).tex = "";

    $('#' + ExpDateTxt).focus();

    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

---

```
function CalculateTotalPrice(Indx, event) {


var txtRequestQty = '#txtReqQty' + Indx.toString();

var txtRecQty = '#txtRecQty' + Indx.toString();


var RecQty = parseInt($(txtRecQty).val());
var ReqQty = parseInt($(txtRequestQty).val());
  if (RecQty <= ReqQty) {

   var txtUnitPrice = '#txtUnitPrice' + Indx.toString();
    var txtTotalPrice = '#txtTotalPrice' + Indx.toString();
    $("txtTotalPrice").prop("readonly", true);


    $(txtTotalPrice).val(RecQty * $(txtUnitPrice).val());

    SetFocus('ddlCompanyName', Indx);
}
else {
    PopupMessage("Required", " Received quantity should be less or equal to Requested Quantity", "alert");
    return false;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

}
return true;
}
```

In these two function i have done the validation for the expiry date and calculation of the total price. I have to used these function at the time of 
saving and do the validation.

Any help plz....

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. Are yo trying to save data or call MVC controller.

Comment: How third function look like ?

Comment: to call the mvc controller